# Spring Cloud Fallback to a different Host ( Not any other controller inside same project )

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Quick Advice please , Let me quickly explain my project structure.   Call flows as below:-

1) React UI -->  gateway microserivce --> APIM microservice--> User details microservice.

What i am trying to Do is . In case "APIM microservice" is down we hit below route ( Adding JWT token)

2) React UI -->  gateway microserivce --> User details microservice

APIM is a third party and we do not know when its down or up. we want our application to be up 24 x 7.

What i tried.

1) @ EnableCircuitBreaker - Hysterix IN gateway microservice. using fallback method. ( Does not solve the purpose as within same project , i need to route request to different host )

2) Using GatewayFilter --> public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) { return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(modifiedRequest).build());}

we can give fallback method name is application.properties like

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0].args.fallbackUri=forward:/userDetails

---

### Gateway microservice is running on 42009 and userDetail microservice is running on 42008.

Both Above ways are fallback within the same project and not to a different host micro service.

Please suggest me a way on how i handle this scenario. I need to forward request to userDetail microservice if APIM is down.

looking forward for reponse.

Thanks,

Comment: Use circuit breaker as before with a fallback, but have the fallback route to another route in the gateway rather than a controller.

Comment: Somethig as below :-
 
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "userDetails")
  public String readingUserList() {
   //if APIM fails  ---------------------------- 
  }

  public String userDetails() {
 URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:42008/recommended");
  return this.restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
  }

?
if Yes, Any other way we have

Comment: can you please post a sample example please for reference, would highly appreciate !